# How to get the value of system()?

Tags: premake

How do I get the current value of system() in premake5?
(and more generally functions like architecture() or platform())

I tried to print it, but it's a function, and when I try to print the return value of system(), I get "bad argument #1 to 'tostring' (value expected)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Premake doesn't work that way, there is no "current" version of the data. You have to specify the context in which you'd like the current set of filters to be applied; take a look at src/base/oven.lua to see how the final data sets are built.

If you just want to drop the value of system (or architecture or platform) into an expression later in the process (and you're using Premake 5), check out [tokens](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/Tokens):

```
targetdir "bin/%{cfg.system}/%{cfg.architecture}"
```

Tokens can also evaluate arbitrary Lua expressions.

```
my_system_map = {   -- must be global, so token evaluator can find it
   windows = "Win32",
   linux = "Posix",
   macosx = "Mac"
}

targetdir "bin/%{my_system_map[cfg.system]}"
```

Helpful?

Comment: Seems like what I want to do :) But... what if I want to map the value of cfg.system to something else? Say, just have an equivalent of "bin/"..mapping[system].."/" ?

Comment: Added another example to my answer to demonstrate.